# How to group multiple imported components of the same module under one name?

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, module

I would like to find an as cleanly a solution as possible to **import multiple components from one module under the module name itself (or any other specified)** in ECMAScript 2015. It would be optimal to have it as a one-liner as well.

---

When importing everything of a module, it already works like charm:

```
import * as Immutable from "immutable"
```

**My app will be on the browserside** (bundles through webpack), however, which induces me to be more selective with imports.

I tried different, intuitive approaches that sprung to mind from other languages or the use of Javascript which didn't work (as import does not follow the typical js rules):

```
import { fromJS } as Immutable from "immutable"
```

or

```
let Immutable = {}
import { fromJS as Immutable.fromJS } from "immutable"
```

---

**A verbose and laborious solution to the problem** is the seperation of imports and where they are used into two files:

In *index_imports.js*:

```
import { fromJS } from "immutable"

const Immutable =
{
  fromJS,
}

export
{
  Immutable,
}
```

Which reduces the import statement in *index.js* to a one-liner:

```
import { Immutable } from "./index_imports.js"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the deduction of my question post:

**A verbose and laborious solution to the problem** is the seperation of imports and where they are used into two files:

In *index_imports.js*:

```
import { fromJS } from "immutable"

const Immutable =
{
  fromJS,
}

export
{
  Immutable,
}
```

Which reduces the import statement in *index.js* to a one-liner:

```
import { Immutable } from "./index_imports.js"
```